# the index of the array created with the map() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React .js
There are 3 arrays `a`, `b`, `c`.
I add array `a` to HTML markup using the `map()` method.
I need:

1. To hang the `onClick` event handler on the elements of the `a` array so that when the element is clicked, this element is reflected to the `<List />` component.
2. The `<List />` component should display the elements of the arrays `b` and `c` with the same indices as the index of the pressed array element `a`.
   For example: in HTML markup I click on the "plum" elements (index = 2). In the `<List />` component you need to get "plum" and the elements "Sophie" and "audi" (index = 2 arrays `b` and `c`)

How to do the above points?

```
export default class App extends Component {
  a = ["Apple", "pear", "plum", "currant", "strawberry"];
  b = ["Amelia", "Oliver", "Sophie", "Alfie", "Jacob"];
  c = ["mercedes", "bmw", "audi", "volkswagen", "hyundai"];

  render() {
    let pp = this.a.map((arr, idx) => {
      return <li key={idx}>{this.a[idx]}</li>;
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul>{pp}</ul>
        </div>
        <List />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Output:**

[image]

Full Example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      a: ["Apple", "pear", "plum", "currant", "strawberry"],
      b: ["Amelia", "Oliver", "Sophie", "Alfie", "Jacob"],
      c: ["mercedes", "bmw", "audi", "volkswagen", "hyundai"],
      index: null
    };
  }

  setIndex = i => {
    console.log(i);
    this.setState({
      index: i
    });
    console.log(this.state.index);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.index !== null && (
          <div>
            <List
              a={this.state.a[this.state.index]}
              b={this.state.b[this.state.index]}
            />
          </div>
        )}
        <div>
          <ul>
            {this.state.a.map((arr, idx) => (
              <li
                onClick={() => {
                  console.log("hi");
                  this.setIndex(idx);
                }}
              >
                {arr}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>{this.props.a}</li>
          <li>{this.props.b}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can check the working example here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hmdoz6?file=src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `onClick` to each `li` inside your `map` function, like so

```
itemsThatMatchIndex = []

getItemsInBAndCThatMatch(index) {
    this.itemsThatMatchIndex = [this.b[index], this.c[index]];
}


render() {
    let pp = this.a.map((arr, idx) => {
      return (<li key={idx}>
          <button onClick={() => this.getItemsInBAndCThatMatch(idx)}>
             {this.a[idx]}
          </button>
     </li>);
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul>{pp}</ul>
        </div>
        <List data={this.itemsThatMatchIndex}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```